# Change YouTube Link from watch to embed dynamically using Jquery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

How can we change List of YouTube URL(links) from **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=....** to **https://www.youtube.com/embed?v=....**  dynamically in Jquery , I am new in html with jquery,please advice me in code.

**my js page:**

```
function vidgallerylist(){
    var url=path+"/customer/video";

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            for(var i=0;i<result.data.length;i++){
                $('#vidlistshow').html(function(i,url){
                    var url = result.data[i].vidgalleryUrl;
                    var id = url.split('watch?v=')[2];

                    $("#tablevidgalleryid").append('<tr><td>'+result.data[i].vidgalleryTitle+'</td><td><iframe width="380" height="258" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + id + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></td></tr>');

                });
            }
            $('#tablevidgalleryid').DataTable();
        }
    }); 
}
```

**html page :**

```
    <h2>List of Video Gallery</h2>        
    <table class="table " id="tablevidgalleryid">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Videos url</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="vidlistshow">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**In My Browser Page Shown like below :**

[image: I want List of Video in this Page dynamically (See Image)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var songsUrl = ["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BdRmjO04kH8", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y7P9UWpHpMs", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ES0oYC0hyD8"];
        $.each(songsUrl, function(index, value){

        var splitLink = value.split('watch?v=')
        var embedLink1 = splitLink.join("embed/")
            $("#result").append(index + ": " + embedLink1 + '<br>');
        });
    });
</script>


<body>
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hello zabih ullah , thank you for quick response. But, I  have  Multiple Url link in my database . show dynamically in html page

Comment: @Rakesh , Just a random thought that if you inject my code inside your for loop, might be it resolves your problem.

Comment: yeah bro, i have added your code. but,  video not playing An error occurred. Please try again later. (Playback ID: M8nWVNpDOl-SSpn2)
Learn More

Comment: $('#vidlistshow').html(function(i,url){
              
              var link = result.data[i].vidgalleryUrl
               var splitLink = link.split('watch?v=')
               var embedLink1 = splitLink.join("embed/")
               console.log(embedLink1)

Comment: My code is not playing video. I am just converting `url` to `embedUrl` and showing it on console. You can check on your console, if you are getting the required result then you can use it.

Comment: okay bro , but can you check  it my js page were i  have used.

Comment: I have edited my answer @Rakesh, i think now it will give you the desired result